# How to disable internet for users in Linux Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: internet

I need to diable internet for the users in linux. I have tried the following command.

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner devuser1 -j REJECT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner devuser1  -j DROP

And tried to enter this command in /etc/network/interfaces . But it is empty.

Comment: All users selected users and why?

Comment: Generally the `uid-owner` is a number, not a string. If the goal is to use characters, you can replace `uid` with `gid` (for *Group* ID): `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --gid-owner devgroup1 -j DROP`

Comment: show us your `/etc/network/interfaces` contents. Are you using an old version of Ubuntu that still uses the `/etc/network/interfaces` file? I load my iptables rules as a post-boot service, but some recommend iptables-pesristent.